# Law of cosines returns 90 degrees for all angles in a triangle?

Tags: python, trigonometry

I'm working on an assignment where I make a class called Triangle that takes in three sides and returns information about the triangle. Specifically, I am trying to calculate the three angles within the triangle, but for some reason I am getting 90 degrees for all angles, which is impossible. I have gone over my code tons of times but can't find the mistake and would greatly appreciate some help. Thank you.

```
from math import acos, degrees, sqrt
import turtle

class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, side_a=None, side_b=None, side_c=None):

        self.side_a = side_a
        self.side_b = side_b
        self.side_c = side_c

    def is_triangle(self):
        return ((self.side_a + self.side_b) > self.side_c) \
               and ((self.side_a + self.side_c) > self.side_b) \
               and ((self.side_b +self.side_c) > self.side_a)

    def perimeter(self):
        if self.is_triangle():
            return self.side_a + self.side_b + self.side_c
        else:
            return None

    def area(self):
        if self.is_triangle():
            s = self.perimeter()/2
            print s
            return sqrt((s*(s-self.side_a)*(s-self.side_b)*(s-self.side_c)))
        else:
            return None

    def a_angle(self):
        if self.is_triangle():
            return degrees(acos((self.side_b**2 + self.side_c**2 - self.side_a**2)/(2*self.side_b*self.side_c)))
        else:
            return None

    def b_angle(self):
        if self.is_triangle():
            return degrees(acos((self.side_c**2 + self.side_a**2 - self.side_b**2)/(2*self.side_c*self.side_a)))
        else:
            return None

    def c_angle(self):
        if self.is_triangle():
            return degrees(acos((self.side_a**2 + self.side_b**2 - self.side_c**2)/(2*self.side_a*self.side_b)))
        else:
            return None

    def angle(self):
        return self.a_angle(), self.b_angle(), self.c_angle()

    def __str__(self):
        pass






tri = Triangle(11, 7, 9)
print tri.is_triangle()
print tri.perimeter()
print tri.area()
print tri.a_angle()
print tri.b_angle()
print tri.c_angle()
print tri.angle()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: The version is Python 2.7

Comment: You've got some duplication there. Factor out the cosine rule into a separate function and pass it the different lengths as parameters. e.g. `def angle_c(a, b, c): return degrees(acos((a**2 + b**2 - c**2)/(2 * a * b)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, division of integers by default truncates the result to an integer, so something like `5/2` will equal 2.  In your case, dividing the sides results in zero.

The simplest way to fix it is to do `from __future__ import division` at the very beginning of your file.  This makes division always return a float.